# Log Equation Write the expression in terms of $\log a$ and $\log b$

Tags: calculus

Guys I need some help with this problem I get the basic concept but I am having trouble with this one question if you can give me a hand.

Write the expression $\log\left(\dfrac{1000}{a^4 \sqrt{b}}\right)$ in terms of $\log a$ and $\log b$.

Comment: We encourage users to accept answers that are helpful. To accept an answer, simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. (You can accept only one answer per question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\log\left(\frac{1000}{a^4 \sqrt{b}}\right) &= \log(1000) - \log(a^4 \sqrt{b}) \quad (\mbox{quotient rule})\\
&= 3 - (\log(a^4) + \log(b^{1/2})) \quad (\mbox{product rule, $\log(1000) = 3$, $\sqrt{b} = b^{1/2}$})\\
&= 3 - 4\log(a) - \frac{1}{2} \log b \qquad (\mbox{distribute negative, power rule})
\end{align*}
$$